# Zooming out UIViews (transformation problems)

Tags: iphone, uiview, cgaffinetransform

So I've used CGAffineTransform to zoom in,

```
CGAffineTransform newTrans2 = CGAffineTransformScale(mainView.transform,1.05,1.05);
mainView.transform = newTrans2;
```

I do this 15 times to have an animation effect.

Now I would like to zoom out such that mainView fits the iPhone frame (0,0,320,480).

Besides, the user is able to pinch in and pinch out, so I really wonder how I can zoom out and reset it in the original space.

How can I do this?

Comment: You are doing this to get 15 different "stages" to make it look like an animation?!

Comment: Yes, is there a better animation to zoom in and out? Sorry, I'm not too good with CoreGraphics, and all I found was this tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use UIView animation, which is simple yet effective. Configure it however you like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[mainView setFrame:CGMakeRect(0,0,320,480)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This helps to do animations, but what I really want is resetting the frame after being transformed many times, so that it fits the window directly. I can't use a scrollview with an imageview because I need to register some UITouches which scrollview takes and does not share with its subviews.

Comment: Dou you want pulsing effect, or why do you use many transformations? Normally only this code is needed - or something similar. Maybe describe what your starting with and what you'd like to accomplish. You can also set a callback when the animation finishes.